# http digest authentication in asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

Is it possible to do http digest authentication with asp.net mvc? If it is possible, is it built in or does it require a lot of work?

Comment: Why do you want to use it? http digest auth is fundamentally flawed. It prevents you from storing securely hashed passwords. Use https together with basic auth or a simple form.

Comment: I'm aware of the pros and cons.

Comment: Impossibility of secure password hashing should be enough to never use it.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Please could you explain more, I would like to know why digest auth is flawed and prevent storing securely password?

Comment: @CuongLe Normally you store a hash of the password, using a slow hashing scheme, such as PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt. The challenge-response system of digest auth on the other hand forces you to store a single iteration md5 hash which cannot be hashed further. Single iteration md5 is fast, making password guessing attacks unnecessarily fast.

Comment: Although the security scheme is flawed there is still valid applications for it. Like when you are forced to have it due to an external part (that is out of your control) that needs to communicate with you using this scheme. So...does anybody have an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a way to secure my login page without SSL. Digest seems to be the best solution in pain HTTP.

This may be what you want

http://httpauthmod.codeplex.com/